# How add arguments to query

Tags: wordpress

i use a Toolset plugin to make view on WP and they give us possibility to manipulate with API. 
I try to add argument to my view but it doesn't work.

here is the function :

```
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_query', 'add_city_tax', 99, 3 );

function add_city_tax( $query_args, $view_settings, $view_id )
{
    if($view_id == 7706)
    {

            $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array
                    (
                        array
                            (
                                [taxonomy] => 'ville',
                                [field] => 'id',
                                [terms] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 220
                                    ),
                                [operator] => 'IN'
                            ),
                        [relation] => 'OR',
                    ),
            );
    }
    $query_args = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $query_args;
}
```

the page make an error

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the output?

Comment: Looks like your array syntax is not correct.

Comment: The page doesn't want to charge...

Comment: What do you mean by "make an error"? Is there any message given that you forgot to share?

Answer (score 1):

The method you are declaring args is not correct. You should not create array like that. Please check following example.

```
    function add_city_tax( $query_args, $view_settings, $view_id ) {
    if($view_id == 7706) {
        $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'ville',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => array( 220 ),
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                    ),
                'relation' => 'OR',
                ),
            );
    }
    $query_args = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $query_args;
}
```

And here doc

Description
When displaying a View listing posts, this filter is applied to the arguments being generated by the View settings before they are passed to the WP_Query class.

Views filters - wpv_filter_query

Note that the filters that you can add to the View are also hooked here, each of them using a different priority that gets up to 100. To ensure that your filter runs after them, you would need to use a higher priority number.

Remember that the filter can take three parameters. If you pass more than one, you need to specify it in your code using the fourth argument:

1
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_query', 'my_callback_function', 99, 3 );
Arguments
array $query_args Τhe query arguments as in WP_Query.

array $view_settings The View settings.

int $view_id The View ID.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work like this.

i have tried like this :

```
function add_city_tax( $query_args, $view_settings, $view_id ) {
    if($view_id == 7706) {
        $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'ville',
                    'field'    => 'id',
                    'terms'    => array( 220 ),
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                    ),
                'relation' => 'AND',
                ),
            );
    }
    $query_args[] = $args ;
    $msg = '<pre>' . print_r($query_args, true) . '</pre>';
    mail('franck@efficonex.fr', 'test', $msg);
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_query', 'add_city_tax', 99, 3 );
```

But it is the same result without filter.

here is the example of api

//Return only posts from the current author when listing posts of type company:
add_filter( 'wpv_filter_query', 'prefix_show_only_current_author' );

```
function prefix_show_only_current_author( $query_args ) {
    global $current_user;
    $types = (array) $query_args['post_type'];
    if ( !is_admin() && in_array( 'company', $types ) ) {
        $query_args['author'] = empty( $current_user->ID ) ? -1 : $current_user->ID;
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```